# Data flow single row transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory, transformation, dataflow, azure-cloud-services, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a transformation can this achieved by dataflow.

[image]

Thanks
ANuj Gupta

Comment: we can't see the picture.

Answer (score 0):

If the column data `CN=SERVICE NOW,OU=TOOL;CN=PYTHON,OU=LANGUAGE;CN=ADF,OU=CLOUD` schema is fixed, then you can use data flow [derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) expression to achieve it.

I just made an example to get output, here's the dataset:
[image]

Data Flow derived column expressions:

1. Col1 column value: `col1` --> `{Col1 }`
2. a column value: `SERVICE NOW`-->`substring(split({ Col2},';')[1], 5,    length(split({ Col2},';')[1])-12)`
3. b column value: PYTHON --> `substring(split({ Col2},';')[2], 4, length(split({ Col2},';')[1])-17)`
4. c column value: `ADF` --> `substring(split({ Col2},';')[3], 4, length(split({ Col2},';')[1])-20)`

Screenshots:
[image]

But if the data is dynamic, we can't do the conversion in Data Factory, it's unachievable.

Comment: Hi Leon same thing I tried in sql but using string_split, I tried yours also but data is huge unstructured & derived column I have to write couple of time may be 100+ columns and also at last data is coming row wise I need column wise.
If you see T-sql Query below it works fine but same query how we can do it in mapping data flow still I am searching.
declare @var varchar(200)= 'CN=SERVICE NOW,OU=TOOL;CN=Citiscan,OU=LANGUAGE;CN=Medicalkit,OU=CLOUD'
select substring(value,4,charindex(',',value) -4 ) from string_Split(@Var,';')
Output comes column wise. 
SERVICE NOW
Citiscan
Medicalkit.

Comment: Hi @anuj, hope you're doing well.  another way is that please add the query as a stored procedure, then using Lookup active + Foreach active with inner Stored procedure active in the pipeline.

Comment: Hi Yes Leon using storeproc  & view that can be done, but still the requirement should be alone handle by adf only. As file coming in blob -- unstructured-- (make it clean/data massage using data flow-- dump it again to blob storage.)  I followed your split also but at the end how to make it in a column wise.

Comment: @anuj the new column need to be set in sink mapping, choose the column you want and mapping to sink column.

Answer (score 0):

Logic : You can get the index of first occurence of 'CN=' and first occurence of comma to get first word between them, ie  Service Now.

Similarly for others.

If I get time I will try to edit this with the actual syntax!

Comment: Hi Monkia, 
It would be helpful if syntax you have specially in dataflow blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The strings are delimited by ;. First split by that(so you get an array) in a derived transform. You can then use the 'map' function to extract out the string before the last =. You will have an array of values(ADF/Python etc). Then you use a flatten transform to convert columns to rows.

Comment: Hi Kiran, How? I used this expression split({Col1}, ';'), there is no output. I am avoiding index strategic reason is that Input col1 is unstructured & huge in size appx 1000+ column entry and in future more will come. If any expression that works for you please  share. I tried below in synapase - declare @var varchar(200)= 'CN=SERVICE NOW,OU=TOOL;CN=Citiscan,OU=LANGUAGE;CN=Medicalkit,OU=CLOUD' select substring(value,4,charindex(',',value) -4 ) from string_Split(@Var,';') Output comes column wise. SERVICE NOW Citiscan Medicalkit. It works same thing need to achieve in dataflow.

Comment: map(split(Col1, ';'),  substring(#item, 4, locate(#item, ',OU='))

This will give you the array of values you need to flatten

Comment: Assign this to a derived column. Then use the flatten transform. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten

Comment: Hi Kiran expression is working fine in adf builder it is giving ["","",""]  in the form of array & when I tried flatten on d column i.e unroll by d[] in output i am getting blank.

Comment: map(split(Col1, ';'), substring(#item, 4, locate(#item, ',OU=')-4)) tried this also. still after flatten output is blank.